# How to Add VM to Inventory?

Tags: java, vmware, datastore, esx

I'm writing a code for VMware ESX to add a .vmx file to the Inventory. This action should be the same as going in the GUI to the Datastore and right-clicking on a .vmx file --> Add to Inventory.

I believe I am supposed to use the method registerVM_Task() and the only parameter I'm missing is the 'host'.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking if registerVM_Task is the right task or are you asking how you should get the host?

Comment: Both is the answer. My train of thought was that I had to somehow pass the *.vmx file to the hostSystem, and from there I'll pass it to registerVM_task().